# Very much: used with adjuncts and noun groups

Tags: adverbs, nouns, adjuncts

Page 307 of Cobuild English Usage reads

> You use *very much* in front of adjuncts, not '*very*': *She does
> things **very much** her own way.*
>
> Sometimes it's used in front of noun groups to emphasize someone or
> something has all the qualities you would expect a particular kind to
> have.
>
> *He was **very much** a seaman.*

Isn't [very much](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very_much#English) modifying the verbs in these examples instead?

Secondly, would both uses be grammatical without *very*, using only **much** ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, “in her own way” is an adverbial phrase (also called an “adjunct”) that modifies the verb. The “very much” modifies the adjunct by intensifying it.

So I do not think you can say that “very much” modifies the verb.

> She does things very much

is not idiomatic.

I think it is more descriptive to say that “very much in her own way” as a whole modifies the verb, but that “very much” considered in isolation modifies the adjunct “in her own way.”

In the second example, the “very much” is modifying the noun phrase “a seaman” in a special idiomatic sense explained in what you have quoted. It means

> He was an excellent seaman, who possessed every nautical skill.

Comment: Would both uses be grammatical without _very_? using only **much** ?

Comment: No. Although both “much” and “very” can be used as independent words, what you quoted is trying to explain that the entire phrase “very much” sometimes is required.